# PHP Match phrase only if outside of an <a href> tag

Tags: php, regex, html

I'm trying automate internal links within pages on my website. I need already linked text to be exempted.

For the following example it should only replace the bolded text (Example).

```
<a class="Example" href="http://www.example.com/">Example</a>

<p>New **Example**</p>
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
$re = '/(\b'.$search.'\b)+((?=.*<a)|(?!.*<\/a>))/';
$str=preg_replace($re, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: Please format your question, it makes no sense as it is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2307070) about why ṫ̨̗̺̭̮̞̗̜̮̗̙̫̺̖̭̯͊ͨ̌͒̍͘͘͟͝h̸͓̩̙͙̻̗͔̞̘̟̩̯͋͑͂͐a̴̧ͨ́ͭ͒ͯ̓͐̇̃ͥ͢҉‌​̨̳̜̤͍͖t̵̳̳͕͉͋̓͐ͦͬ̈́̀̚‌ is a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow @ThomasAyoub's advice. Use DOM functionalities to achieve such a task but this is a way to match desired word with Regular Expressions if you want to see:

```
<a\b[^>]+>.*?<\/a>\K|Example
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/RaUuzG/1)